# SOQL Query with 'NOT IN' and Doesn't Start With Conditions

Tags: apex, soql

I have a Custom Status field on Account Object With Status like IA, EA, MI etc.

What is the best way to write a SOQL Query for following conditions:

SELECT * from Account WHERE Id IN :(SET) AND Status NOT IN (LIST) AND Status Doesn't Start With 'E'

This is What I tried but It doesn't seem to be working :

```
string tempNSecondEligibility = label.Sample1;// expected output - (E%) 
string tempNFirstEligibility = label.Sample1;//expected output - (IA,MI)
List<String> lstAlpha = tempNFirstEligibility.split(',');

List<Account> lstWslrAct = [SELECT *  FROM Account where Id IN : setId AND (NOT(WSLR_TYP_CD_US__C IN :lstAlpha OR WSLR_TYP_CD_US__C Like :tempNSecondEligibility))];
```

I  am expecting the output as accounts where status isn't IA or MI but I am getting accounts with aforementioned status.

Thanks.

Comment: Please always include any  error message you get verbatim.

Comment: Apologies but It Doesn't give any error, It compiles but output is not what is expected.

Comment: So please **[edit]** your post to reflect what behavior you observe and how it diverges from your expectation.

Comment: Without knowing what you have specified in your three bind variables, it will still be difficult to assist you.

Comment: Out of three two are from Label as I explained in comments, third is a set of Id's upon which I have to put the conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an `OR` clause unless you absolutely cannot avoid it. Here, you should simply continue to use `AND` and negate each clause individually:

```
WHERE Id IN :setId
AND WSLR_TYP_CD_US__C NOT IN :lstAlpha
AND NOT WSLR_TYP_CD_US__C LIKE :tempNSecondEligibility
```

Comment: Hi, Adrian, Third Line is giving Compilation Error => unexpected token: LIKE